# Dynamic Table with Crystal Report in Visual C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, crystal-reports, report

I want to create a dynamic table whose columns attributes are undefined and should be updated in runtime. And this table should be used in crystal report. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps what you need is to 
Insert, CrossTab...
Tough to tell though because the question is vague.